# .NET SDK GetRecipientView() example and existing envelope

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using the DocuSign .NET SDK library to create the recipient view. It works fine when I pass a document into the Create Envelope Method but I don't want to create a new envelope... I want to set the EnvelopeId and get the recipient view specifically for the my already existing envelope;

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR version: To provide the Recipient View, your app must also create the envelope. In particular, you need to set the [clientUserId](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Recipients/Signers%20Recipient.htm) value. This is an important security issue. Your app then supplies the same clientUserId when your app creates the Recipient view

**Details**

When your app creates the Recipient View to enable the signer to review/sign the document, your app is providing authentication assurance to DocuSign. That is, your app is guaranteeing that the human is the right person to review/sign the document.

But how does DocuSign know that your app is itself authorized to authenticate the signer? The *clientUserId* value is used for this. Your app supplies this field and its value when you create/send the envelope. Your app must then provide the same value for the field when you ask DocuSign to create the Recipient View.